# algorithm numbering

Tags: numbering, algorithms, algorithmicx

I am having trouble numbering and referencing algorithms.

I want to have the references labeled by the chapter, then within the chapter, such as:

First algorithm in chapter 1 - **Algorithm 1.1**

Second algorithm in chapter 1 - **Algorithm 1.2**

Here's a MWE of what I'm doing

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{thesis}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{algorithm}} 

\begin{document} 

\chapter{First Chapter}

\begin{algorithm} 
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Some code here 
  \end{algorithmic} 
  \label{alg:algorithm1}
\end{algorithm}

Algorithm \ref{alg:algorithm1} states blah blah blah. 

\end{document}
```

When I reference algorithm1, I get **Algorithm I** (where I is the roman numeral for 1) instead of **Algorithm 1.1**.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to use `\caption` *before* `\label`; otherwise, the string picked for the reference will be the last one where an anchor was set (typically the one of a sectional unit), in this case, the one from `\chapter`. Here's a modified version of your code showing the desired result:

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{book}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{algorithm}} 

\begin{document} 

\chapter{First Chapter}

\begin{algorithm} 
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Some code here 
  \end{algorithmic} 
  \caption{A test algorithm}
  \label{alg:algorithm1}
\end{algorithm}

Algorithm~\ref{alg:algorithm1} states blah blah blah and algorithm~\ref{alg:algorithm2} states blah blah blah. 

\begin{algorithm} 
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Some code here 
  \end{algorithmic} 
  \caption{Another test algorithm}
  \label{alg:algorithm2}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to give explicit captions to your algorithms, you can use the `\phantomcaption` command from the `caption` package (this, however, could be confusing since you are referencing by number some objects which aren't really numbered):

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage{caption}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{algorithm}} 

\begin{document} 

\chapter{First Chapter}

\begin{algorithm} 
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Some code here 
  \end{algorithmic} 
  \phantomcaption
  \label{alg:algorithm1}
\end{algorithm}

Algorithm~\ref{alg:algorithm1} states blah blah blah and algorithm~\ref{alg:algorithm2} states blah blah blah. 

\begin{algorithm} 
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Some code here 
  \end{algorithmic} 
  \phantomcaption
  \label{alg:algorithm2}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Mistake 1 was a typo. In my actual document, `\ref` matched `\label` exactly. I'll edit my post so that they match.

Comment: @COM Ah, I see. I have then also edited my answer to reflect this.